# WordPress blog_content character limit

Tags: php, wordpress, blogs, php-include

Great people of Stack, I once again require your assistance.

I currently have an external website that pulls through blog content from a sub-folder containing a WordPress installation, for example:

Website A: External Static Website
Website B: WordPress installation

I have the posts including on the homepage of Website A using the following code.

WordPress call:

```
<?php  
//db parameters  
$db_username = '###';  
$db_password = '###';  
$db_database = '###';  

$blog_url = 'http://www.website.com/blog/';

//connect to the database  
mysql_connect('###', $db_username, $db_password);  
@mysql_select_db($db_database) or die("Unable to select database");  

//get data from database -- !IMPORTANT, the "LIMIT 5" means how many posts will appear. Change the 5 to any whole number.  
$query = "Select * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type='post' AND post_status='publish' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";   

$query_result = mysql_query($query);  
$num_rows = mysql_numrows($query_result);  

//close database connection  
mysql_close();  

// html page starts after 
?>
```

The Blog Post inclusion:

```
<div class="contentBox">
    <?php  
    for($i=0; $i< $num_rows; $i++){   

   //assign data to variables, $i is the row number, which increases with each run of the loop  
   $blog_date = mysql_result($query_result, $i, "post_date");  
   $blog_title = mysql_result($query_result, $i, "post_title");  
   $blog_content = mysql_result($query_result, $i, "post_content");  
   //$blog_permalink = mysql_result($query_result, $i, "guid"); //use this line for p=11 format.  

   $blog_permalink = $blog_url . mysql_result($query_result, $i, "post_name"); //combine blog url, with permalink title. Use this for title format  

                        //format date  
                        $blog_date = strtotime($blog_date);  
                        $blog_date = strftime("%b %e", $blog_date);  

                        //the following HTML content will be generated on the page as many times as the loop runs. In this case 5.  
                        ?>
                        <div class="post"></div>  
                        <img src="img/headers/news-from.png" /><br />

                                <p class="blogName"><a href="http://www.website.com/blog"><?php echo $blog_title; ?></a></p>  

                                <p style="margin-top: -10px; margin-right: 10px;"><?php echo $blog_content;?></p>  

                                <p>Submitted on: <span class="green"><?php echo $blog_date; ?></span></p>   

                                <p><a href=”<?php echo $blog_permalink; ?>”>Read Full Post</a></p>  
                        <?php  
                            } //end the for loop  
                        ?>
                    </div>
```

This works perfectly, it pulls the necessary post and displays it, all wonderfully formatted etc. The problem I have is that I really need to limit the character count that is pulled through, as it stands, this currently echo's the entire post, I only need to echo the first 15 characters of the post. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can limit the character output by echoing the following.

From:

```
 <p style="margin-top: -10px; margin-right: 10px;"><?php echo $blog_content;?></p>
```

To:

```
 <p style="martin-top: -10px; margin-right: 10px;"><?php echo substr($blog_content,0,40); ?></p>
```

Comment: Didn't work i'm afraid, it just posts a 1 to the paragraph instead of the post content?

Comment: I had to wait before being allowed to accept the answer, he now has a lovely green tick to accompany his answer :)

Answer (score 2):

This may seem like an easyish solution to a complex question, but why not use a `substr` to trim down the post??

You could even do this by setting a seperate variable?

e.g.

```
$trimmed_post = substr($blog_content, 0,15);
```

All this has done is create a new variable to display on the page which starts at character 0 of your `$blog_content` variable, and cuts off after 15 characters.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to remove the line

```
echo $blog_content;
```

and replace it with

```
echo substr(strip_tags($blog_content), 0, 50);
```

Changing 50 to your desired length.